# EF4 code first many to many relationship to external entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, ef4-code-only

### Problem

I've got two classes:

- OfficeProfile: exists within my EF model
- BusinessUnit: comes from an external source, e.g. a web service

There is a many to many relationship between office profiles and business units, which I'd like to represent in a link table `OfficeProfilesBusinessUnits`. I don't want to end up with a `BusinessUnits` table however that contains a list of business units as these are stored in an external domain outside of my control.

Is it possible to achieve this?

```
public class OfficeProfile
{
    public OfficeProfile()
    {
        ContactNumbers = new HashSet<ContactNumber>();
        BusinessUnits = new HashSet<BusinessUnit>();
    }

    public int OfficeProfileId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits { get; private set; }
}

public class BusinessUnit
{
    public BusinessUnit(string code, string name, BusinessUnit parent)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BusinessUnit Parent { get; set; }
}
```

### What I've tried

I've tried ignoring the `BusinessUnit` entity, however that omits the link table.

I've tried ignoring the BusinessUnit entity whilst mapping the many-to-many relationship, however that throws an `InvalidOperationException` stating

> The navigation property 'BusinessUnits' is not a declared property on
>   type 'OfficeProfile'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded
>   from the model and that it is a valid navigation property

.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra entity which would only have an ID and a link to the BusinessUnit. In your Entity Model you would then ignore the BusinessUnit but add the link entity so you get the many to many relation link table.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping to avoid creating another entity. Do you know whether it is possible to configure EF to behave as described with just the two entities?

Comment: What if you would just add a ICollection<int> BusinessUnitIds to your entity? And then ignore the whole BusinessUnits collection?